# Credential Manager CredentialBlob clear text

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-credential-provider

if I save a new credential with:

```
CREDENTIALW cred = { 0 };
...
cred.Type = CRED_TYPE_GENERIC;
cred.TargetName = convert("PIN");
cred.CredentialBlob = (LPBYTE)pBlob; // value here: "password"
..
BOOL ok = ::CredWriteW(&cred, 0);
...
```

and then received it:

```
PCREDENTIALW pcred;
BOOL ok = ::CredReadW(L"PIN", CRED_TYPE_GENERIC, 0, &pcred);
```

I can see the password in clear text. Should I encrypt/ decrypt the value CredentialBlob separately or is it also possible to encrypt the values ​​with the Win32 API?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use a [CryptProtectData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptprotectdata) and [CryptUnprotectData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptunprotectdata) functions pair from [DPAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dpapi/#functions) to protect your data.

If your code (or any part) will be work as `SYSTEM` account (or any service account) you need to set `CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE` flag in `dwFlags` parameter:

> When this flag is set, it associates the data encrypted with the current computer instead of with an individual user. Any user on the computer on which CryptProtectData is called can use CryptUnprotectData to decrypt the data.